# How to show local Storage Value in Primeng dropdown

Tags: javascript, json, angular, local-storage, primeng

I want to use local storage for the dropdown selected option by the user, so he can see the same option on page reload.

my dropdown

```
 <p-dropdown 
[options]="languages" 
[(ngModel)]="selectedLanguage" optionLabel="name"
(onChange)="onChangeDropDown(selectedLanguage)"></p-dropdown>
```

What I tried:

Saving selected language to local storage which shows as [object, object] in local storage

```
    onChangeDropDown(selectedLanguage: string) {
        localStorage.setItem('language', this.selectedLanguage);
}
```

getting languages from a JSON file

```
// its not working
 this.selectedLanguage = localStorage.getItem('language');

//Getting languages from json file
 this.httpClient.get<any>('./languages.json')
            .toPromise()
            .then(res => res.data as any[])
            .then(data => this.languages = data);
```

my json file

```
{
    "data": [
        
        {
            "name": "English",
            "id": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sindhi",
            "id": "2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Arabic",
            "id": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am very new to primeNG, so I don't know how to use local storage value in p-dropdown. Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: Mismatch between what you're getting and setting, either change to `this.selectedLanguage.name = localStorage.getItem('selectedLanguage');` or `localStorage.setItem('selectedLanguage', this.selectedLanguage);`

Comment: I did try  `this.selectedLanguage.name = localStorage.getItem('selectedLanguage');` nothing happend. I noted ngModel does not show the value even hard coded string.

Comment: You'll need to provide all relevant code, there is quite a bit missing.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it because you are saving `this.selectedLanguage.name` and loading it as `this.selectedLanguage` so you have the name in this variable then?

You should search `languages` by name with the value from local storage.

```
this.selectedLanguage = languages.find((l) => l.name === localStorage.getItem('selectedLanguage'))
```

Comment: I console `this.selectedLanguage.name` it returns the correct value and saved in the localStorage.